# Single Page Application issue with spring cloud gateway token relay openid connect

Tags: spring, keycloak, single-page-application, openid-connect, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm working on microservice architecture using spring cloud gateway token relay openid connect and Keycloak as provider.
Everything is working right, but when trying to access a protected endpoint from Frontend app, I face Cors issue with 302 error.

Is there a possibility to get help in the community?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the webOrigins value of the client you use in the Keycloak.
Realm settings -> clients -> {your client}

[image: Example]